# How to build a set of closed chains with a sequence of different vertices?

Tags: graphs, subsequences

I have a set of many bi-directional links like
`A-B, A-C, B-C, A-D, C-D, D-E, etc.`

I need to find a set of many closed chains with a sequence of different vertices (vertex-disjoint cycles).
It would be better if I can find them all.

How I solve the problem right now:

1. I build a directed graph by these links.
2. I take one of the vertices and then go to the others by edges, building walks.
3. I take the last walks' vertices one by one and then go to the others vertices except those that have already passed, continue building walks.
4. Repeat step 3 for each walk until I reach the start vertex.
   4a. If other vertices are over and I could not build a closed chain, I delete the walk.

I apologize for my ignorance of graph theory.
Perhaps I am reinventing the wheel? 
Perhaps there is already a solution to this issue? 
Please tell me.

Additional information:

- The set of links is about 10,000.
- The directed graph may have unconnected islands of subgraphs.

What problems in my realization I want to solve:

1. I have to build many walks that will be deleted sooner or later because they are not closed chains.
2. I have to check which vertices have already been passed in order to get the next ones.

***UPDATE***

**For what I want to apply it.**

I need to filter out incoming incorrect currency pairs' data by their prices. Every currency pair has two current prices: (best) ask and (best) bid. The currency pair's data will be considered valid if it is possible to build an unprofitable exchanging closed chain (vertex-disjoint cycle) containing at least 4 vertices. (Cycle A-B-A is always valid.)

The closed chain is considered unprofitable when the product of the chain's asks is bigger than 1 and the product of the chain's bids is less than 1.

$\prod A_i>1,$

$\prod B_i<1$

In this case, each currency pair in the chain is valid.

At the same time, finding an invalid chain is not a consequence of the fact that the data is invalid. Only the failure to find a valid chain will be it.

Comment: What is a "closed chain"? Do you mean a [cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_(graph_theory))? Is your question the following: given an undirected graph, find a set of vertex-disjoint cycles of maximum cardinality?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Yes, I mean a cycle. I do not know anything about `maximum cardinality`, but yes, it may be an undirected graph, and I want to find a set of vertex-disjoint cycles. If `maximum cardinality` helps to find a solution, good too.

Comment: You need to define your question precisely. If you just want to find *some* collection of vertex-disjoint cycles, you can take the empty collection, or perhaps just one arbitrary cycle. I suppose you're after something more refined, but you'll have to tell us what exactly.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I want to find some collection of vertex-disjoint cycles. The larger the collection and the longer the cycle, the better. What do you mean by "take the empty collection"?

Comment: The empty set is also a collection of vertex-disjoint cycles, and so solves your problem. In order to help you, we need to understand what you’re looking for.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Ok, I want to find some collection of vertex-disjoint cycles. The empty set does not solve my problem.

Comment: I agree with @YuvalFilmus. Let me try to restate it another way. We need a more precise problem statement, in the question.  You say that that the empty set doesn't meet your needs, but I don't see any requirement in your question that it violates.  I suspect you have some criterion that you are trying to optimize over: maximize the total number of cycles; or maximize the total number of vertices covered by those cycles; or something.  But we need you to tell us what that is.  Don't force us to guess.  I hope you can [edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: Possibly relevant: kidney exchange algorithms.  e.g., https://www.coalitiontheory.net/content/kidney-exchange-application-matching-theory-and-mechanism-design

Comment: @D.W. I added information about what that is. Please see the update block.